# Making a GtkButton round

Tags: gtk

How can I make GtkBtton round in shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options.

- Tweak the style. There is no roundness option in the base set. Some theme engines may provide border image specification or roundness but it will not work everywhere.
- Force a theme that looks the way you want it too. This is not too hard you just load a gtkrc string that specifies the theme you want. You will need to ensure users have the theme or are ok with the fallback.
- Subclass the button and draw it yourself. One way is to set border and relief to 0, pack an image, and respond to state change events to use appropriate pre-light (hover) images. Another way is to rewrite the expose event and draw the button as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Can you post with a sample where drawing button is undertaken in expose event method.

Comment: G_DEFINE_TYPE( RButton, rbutton, GTK_TYPE_BUTTON )
static void rbutton_class_init( RButtonClass *klass ) {
  ((GtkWidgetClass*)klass)->expose_event = rbutton_expose;
}

Comment: Replace gtk_button_paint in the following:

static gint rbutton_expose (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event) {
  if(GTK_WIDGET_DRAWABLE (widget)) {
    GtkWidget *child = GTK_BIN(widget)->child;
    GtkButton *button = GTK_BUTTON(widget);
    GtkStateType state_type = GTK_WIDGET_STATE (widget);
    GtkShadowType shadow_type = button->depressed ? GTK_SHADOW_IN : GTK_SHADOW_OUT;
    _gtk_button_paint (button, &event->area, state_type, shadow_type, "button", "buttondefault");
    if(child)
 gtk_container_propagate_expose(GTK_CONTAINER(widget), child, event);
  }
  return FALSE;
}

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer said:

> There is no roundness option in the base set.

Well, there is now! See [the `GTKWidget` documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html):

> In special cases, buttons can be made round by adding the .circular style class.

So, for example:

```
gtk_style_context_add_class (gtk_widget_get_style_context (button),
                             "circular");
```

This works using both of the standard themes, Adwaita and HighContrast.

In GTK4, there are [convenience functions](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-add-css-class) to avoid having to get the `StyleContext` yourself:

```
gtk_widget_add_css_class (button, "circular");
```

The above assume`button` is a `GtkWidget*`. If, instead, it's a `GtkButton*` or subclass, just substitute in `GTK_WIDGET (button)` of course.