# Python GTK+ 3: How to make a button circular?

Tags: python, gtk3

so basically I want to take a Gtk.Button, which is by default a rectangle, and turn it into a circle. According to https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html you can do this by adding the .circular class. However, I'm not quite sure what is meant by this, or how to do it. Is it something that I need to add to my CSS file? Thanks.

Comment: Check the answer here: [hexagon buttons in GTK+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957525/hexagon-buttons-in-gtk).

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't quite answer my question. How do I apply the .circular style class?

Comment: I realized that after I post. Sorry. I'm trying to find something though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can make a button circular using Css :-

```
    button{
          background-image: none;
          border-radius: 40px;
          padding: 30px 0px;
     }
```

You just have to modify the values for your button size ...

Adding the style class work only with a few themes.To do that you have to

```
gtk_style_context_add_class(
    gtk_widget_get_style_context( GTK_WIDGET(button) ),
    "circular"
);
```

add the style context 
[Making a GtkButton round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212385/making-a-gtkbutton-round)

Comment: The question was regarding Python, but this is C code. What is Python GTK equivalent of `gtk_style_context_add_class` ?

Comment: Well it appears to be:        `context = button.get_style_context()    [newline]
        context.add_class("circular")`